# Jquery/js, taking a value from textfield and using ajax to send it to the server

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to use this plugin: http://jstepper.emkay.dk/Default.aspx to be able to use "mousewheel" value incrementation.

This plugin offers a function onStep, which will run a my own function each time a value is incremented. Now it would be real simple to just send new value to the ajax function, but that would mean hundreds, if not thousands of POST requests, lots of mysql inserts/updates, it would be very messy...

I am trying to implement somekind of a timer that would take the value from the textfield, wait 1000milliseconds and then post it to the server, whenever a user should scroll for more values, it would cancel the previous timeout and start counting again.

This introduced two problems, first - if a user scrolls one textfield and then immediately starts scrolling the next textfield the previous textfield data wouldn't be sent, because the new field would take the control of the timer.

And secondly, I couldn't get the values anyway I tried, this is probably easy to fix, I just have to figure out how to...

So I'm hoping that someone might help me in this, because I am stomped.

```
$(".basket_input").jStepper({onStep:function(){ajaxSleeper(this.value, this.id)}});

var timer = 0;

function ajaxSleeper(val1,val2){
clearTimeout(timer);

timer = setTimeout(function(){
ajaxUpdate(val1,val2);
//alert('updated!');
}, 3000);

}
```

HTML

```
<td><input class="basket_input" size="5" maxlength="6" type="text" value="" name="1939" id="1939" /></td>
```

Comment: Why not just send the request on `blur` event?

Comment: @Demian nice point, for something this simple (it seems like a quantity input box, imo) would makes sense to have it fire onblur/onunload. I can only see this being useful if a lot of information is input in this box, and it's an auto-save type feature. Plently of plugins out there for that already though. :)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest thing to do would be to use `$.data` to set the timer and keep using the context of the actual object.

### jQuery

```
var $basket_input = $(".basket_input");
$basket_input.jStepper({
    onStep: function() {
        ajaxSleeper.call($basket_input.get(0)); // Call the function using the
                                    // element as the context
    }
});


function ajaxSleeper() {
    // Get any timer that could be set for this element
    var thisTimer = $(this).data('timer');
    
    // Clear it if there is one
    if (thisTimer) clearTimeout(thisTimer);
    
    // We need this as the context in setTimeout will change to "window" object
    // Yet we want to reference this object in the setTimeout
    var $that = $(this);
    
    $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(function() {
        ajaxUpdate($that.val(), $that.attr('id'));
        //alert('updated!');
        }, 3000);
    );
}
```

Comment: using "ajaxSleeper.call(this);" Would actually use the jStepper object instead, not the jq selector. This is why I can't get any values to pass on to my function.

Comment: Hm, sorry, but it still isn't working for me. It does use the right object now, but retrieving values doesn't work.

Comment: Do you want to update with the value in the input box, then the id of that element i.e. `id="blah"`? There could be a problem with ajaxUpdate?

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions.

If you haven't seen Underscore.js, you should. They have a `_.throttle()` that will do exactly what you want, along with a million other useful things.

If you don't want to use another library, you're close.

```
var timer;

var fireOffMyRequest = function()
{
    // ... FIRE EVERYTHING! ...
};

var somethingThatGetsFiredOften = function()
{
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(fireOffMyRequest, 4000);
};
```

That limits to 4 seconds; you could change the 4000 to reflect whatever you want the throttle limit to be.

**edit**: I forgot to address your timer issue. Store off the timer onto the HTML element:

```
$(this).data('timer', timer);
```

Comment: Now that I've looked more closely at your code, it actually should work. Are you sure you don't have a variable naming conflict somewhere?